# Android Video Recording of OpenGL surface (GLSURFACEVIEW)

Tags: android, opengl-es, mediarecorder

I am working on a project where we need to record the rendered OpenGL surface. (for example if we use GLsurfaceView, we need to record the surface along with the audio from the MIC)

Presently I am using MediaRecorder API by setting the video source as the `VIDEO_SOURCE_GRALLOC_BUFFER`.

I am using the following [sample](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/master/media/libstagefright/tests/SurfaceMediaSource_test.cpp) as the base code

I wanted to know ....

1. Is this the right way? . Is there any better alternate ?
2. The sample test given in the link is recording the audio and video of the EGLSURFACE but it is not displayed properly.

What might be the reason?
 Any help/pointers is really appreciated.

thanks,
Satish

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The code you reference isn't a sample, but rather internal test code that exercises a non-public interface.  `SurfaceMediaSource` could change or disappear in a future release and break your code.

**Update:**
Android 4.3 (API 18) allows [Surface input](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html#createInputSurface%28%29) to `MediaCodec`.  The [EncodeAndMuxTest](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/#EncodeAndMuxTest) sample demonstrates recording OpenGL ES frames to a .mp4 file.

The `MediaRecorder` class doesn't take Surface input, so in your case you'd need to record the audio separately and then combine it with the new [MediaMuxer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMuxer.html) class.

**Update #2:**
Android 5.0 (API 21) allows [Surface input](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html#getSurface()) to MediaRecorder, which is often much more convenient than MediaCodec.  If you neeed to use MediaCodec, there is an example showing three different ways of recording OpenGL ES output with it in [Grafika's](https://github.com/google/grafika) "record GL activity".

The [MediaProjection](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/projection/MediaProjection.html) class can also be useful for screen recording.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the information. At present we are proceeding with glreadpixels which is decreasing the the FPS.

Comment: Just logged in just to say you are a life saver. Now, on to finding a way to do it on iOS as well.

Comment: MediaRecorder Surface Source is so buggy... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51332386/mediarecorder-and-videosource-surface-stop-failed-1007-a-serious-android-bug

Comment: @user924: The code you reference creates a bitmap, and sets it as a texture with `glTexImage2D()`, but doesn't include any code to render the texture. If you're not sure how to do that, file a new question with [android] and [opengl-es] tags (and possibly [grafika]).

Comment: @fadden I made some progress https://github.com/google/grafika/issues/74#issuecomment-406852804 but it draws bitmap with black background (even If I set Transparent color for canvas), what could be wrong? p.s. I used this cloned project  https://github.com/crearo/grafika

Comment: MediaRecorder setInputSurface need API 23