# How to record as video what happening inside View? (Android)

Tags: android, video, record

Is it possible to record all actions inside some View in Android as video? Maybe using C/C++ or anything else?

I know that there is way to record using shell, but root is required. It would be better without. Also we would make it from SDK Version 16.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the javacv library to combine a set of bitmaps taken from the view;
the code will look like this:

```
FFmpegFrameRecorder recorder = new FFmpegFrameRecorder("/sdcard/test.mp4",256,256);
try {
    recorder.setVideoCodec(avcodec.AV_CODEC_ID_MPEG4);
    recorder.setFormat("mp4");
    recorder.setFrameRate(30);
    recorder.setPixelFormat(avutil.PIX_FMT_YUV420P10);
    recorder.setVideoBitrate(1200);
    recorder.startUnsafe();
    for (int i=0;i< 5;i++)
    {
        view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
        view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
        recorder.record(bitmap);
    }
    recorder.stop();
}
catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And here is a [full example](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv/blob/master/samples/RecordActivity.java) on how to record

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried to use the library. It seems that it is right for me. But I have a question, is it possible to record 30 bitmaps per second? Otherwise, to call `Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getDrawingCache());` 30 times in one second? How can it affect the performance?

Comment: What is v1? This api doesn't work anymore. recoder.record doesn't take bitmap.

Comment: @JeffreyLiu `v1` is your View from what you want to take a screen =)

Comment: @JeffreyLiu didi you get any solution? i'm getting same error
 recorder.record(bitmap);  required org.bytedeco.javacv.Frame not Bitmap

Comment: No I have not @Priyank

Answer (score 6):

You can get screen shots of your app's Views with a [well-known technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661536/how-to-programmatically-take-a-screenshot-in-android).  If you capture several consecutive images you can combine them into a video.

If you want to do this live with a higher frame rate, the recommended approach is to use a virtual display through the [MediaProjection](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/projection/MediaProjection.html) class, feeding the output into a video encoder.  This requires API 21.

Recording the screen on an API 16 device would require native code and the use of [non-public interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28720056/what-is-the-alternative-to-use-createinputsurface-on-api-17-and-below/).  It's possible but not easy.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer! I have considered the options to use this technique (video from images) as you and @androidLover have suggested. But I think that this option would not be best for my problem, because I need to capture with a high frame rate. I suppose encoder will not have time to record at 30 frames per second. Is it so?

Comment: The hardware video codec will be able to keep up with 30fps at a reasonable resolution (720p or 1080p) on most devices. The trouble is getting the frames rendered and into the encoder that fast. You really want to keep all of the data in the GPU and video codec.

Comment: Hi @fadden please elaborate more on the 'MediaProjection' approach. Some sort of code snippet would be very helpful.

Comment: How to record just a view, not the whole screen?

Answer (score 0):

You can check this for capturing a view i tried on cardView layout and it worked perfectly fine

For Video Recording

https://github.com/z4hyoung/ViewRecorder

For Image Capturing

```
fun loadBitmapFromView(v: View): Bitmap? {
        val b: Bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.width, v.height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
        val c = Canvas(b)
        v.draw(c)
        return b
    }

val fos: OutputStream = FileOutputStream(fileDir)

            fos.use {
                // Finally writing the bitmap to the output stream that we opened
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, it)
            }
```