# Black and white video stream background in ARCore app

Tags: java, android, background-color, augmented-reality, arcore

I'm working on AR Android app and when I get close to a renderable I want to make the colors of the AR video stream black-and-white, except the renderables of course. I searched the docs but it seams I cannot access the video stream to do it as shown in [Exploring AR interaction (Google I/O '18)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bUGhG-AZpu0&feature=youtu.be&t=13m14s).

Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

To get a video stream from ARCore requires drawing the texture into a **OpenGL 3.1 Context** what is being captured. You can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40191950/how-can-i-draw-on-a-video-while-recording-it-in-android-and-save-the-video-and) how to do it.

After you've captured a video stream, the simplest way to **convert colour `video`/`image` into grayscale one** (the average of red, green, and blue) is to use a `Colour Matrix` with zero saturation.

Here is an excerpt of Java code how to do it programmatically:

```
ColorMatrix BW_matrix = new ColorMatrix();
BW_matrix.setSaturation(0);

ColorMatrixColorFilter BW_filter = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(BW_matrix);
imageview.setColorFilter(BW_filter);
```

You need to apply it only to video stream from phone's camera, not to the rendered result after adding Sceneform's 3D models to the scene.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I went on with other things in my project, but I put your post into my TODO list and when I hit this very topic again I will circle back here and try it. My feedback and maybe a mark as solution will come definitely.

Comment: Ok, I'll be waiting for a result.

Comment: how yo you apply the transformation to the video stream from the phone camera?