# Modify camera feed in ARCore

Tags: android, arcore, sceneform

Hy

I'm using ARCore with SceneForm on Android.
I would like to apply a fragment shader to the camera feed to make it black & white for example. How could I do that?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52868954/black-and-white-video-stream-background-in-arcore-app) link could help you

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: i tried to use the shared camera feature to create an external texture and display it as a node in front of the camera, not working (yet)