# How to record GLSurfaceView in Android Native C++?

Tags: java, android, c++, opengl-es

I am now working on timelapse feature for my android application. I used android native c++ with opengl es 3.0 to develop a application. I search through internet i found that here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16274569/android-video-recording-of-opengl-surface-glsurfaceview](https://stackoverflow.com). [https://bigflake.com/mediacodec/#EncodeAndMuxTest](https://stackoverflow.com)EGL14 class to create recordable surfaceview. can anyone explain how to integrate this with mine.

```
public class CCEEngineView extends GLSurfaceView {

    public CCERenderer renderer;

    public CCEEngineView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        Log.e("CCEENgineView","const1");
        this.initialize();
    }

    public CCEEngineView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        Log.e("CCEENgineView","const2");
        this.initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        Log.e("CCEENgineView","const3");
        this.setEGLContextClientVersion(3);
        this.setPreserveEGLContextOnPause(true);
        this.setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 0, 0);
        //this.setEGLConfigChooser(new MultisampleConfigChooser());
        this.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFFFFFF);

        this.renderer = new CCERenderer();
        this.setRenderer(this.renderer);
        //Log.e("CCEEngineView:","initialize renderer");
        //this.setOnTouchListener(this);
        //scaleGestureDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(getContext(), this);
    }
}
```

this my view to render opengles textures.

can anyone explain how to do record my GLSurfaceview?